# How to put form class into tab control in anotherone

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a C# program that has two forms. One form contains tab control and the other is a standalone form with many controls.

The question is: Is it possible to integrate this form into the tab control of the first control of the first form or I have to rewrite all the code and put them into the tab control?

I use C# Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: You're looking for the `UserControl` class, not the `Form` class—tab controls can host UserControls, but not Forms. You can copy and paste all the controls from the `Form` onto the `UserControl` at design time and save yourself a lot of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, it is possible.  However, I would strongly recommend that you do not use parented forms.   Instead, move controls to the UserContol and add instances of this UserControl to the second form and TabPage of the TabControl.

Here is the code showing how to add a control to the TabPage:

```
Form f = new Form();
            f.TopLevel = false;
            f.BackColor = Color.Green;
            f.Visible = true;
            tabPage1.Controls.Add(f);
```

**But**, I strongly recommend that you use the UserControl based approach.

Answer (score 1):

At runtime you can make that second form as child/content of first form tab.

Not directly though.

For that you can create your second form as a usercontrol, move all of the code from your second form to the usercontrol and then use this usercontrol as `TabPages` content